# Angular: Conditional field doesn't work with server side

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a conditional field like this :

```
<form ng-app="myApp" name="frm">
    <select ng-model="NewBranchRequest.BranchTypeCode">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">third</option>
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
    </select>
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" name="power" ng-model="NewBranchRequest.PwrCnt" placeholder="sad" ng-required="NewBranchRequest.BranchTypeCode==0">
          <span style="color:red" ng-show="frm.power.$invalid">
                *
            </span>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/56wt39y8/)
it works, but option fill from server and it doesn't work.

**UPDATE**
Check This ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sadeghbayan/MTfRD/1452/)*** which is not working .

All i want is after select **Bug** in select list, input get rquired .

Any idea ?

Comment: A little more detail?

Comment: if it's not clear, tell me what do you need please

Comment: Be specific, please. "it doesn't work" means what? How are you loading it? Where is your controller code?

Comment: wait a minute, i'll give you a good explation in a minute

Comment: please check my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In http://jsfiddle.net/sadeghbayan/MTfRD/1452/

change

```
ng-required="form.type==0"
```

to

```
ng-required="form.type=='bug'"
```

I made the changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/1453/

---

In addition, if you want to get the json object in form.type you can change this

```
ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions'
```

to

```
ng-options='option.value for option in typeOptions'
```

Comment: thx, but i dont have a value in my jason.
my json:[Object { MainCode=956, SubCode=1, ParamDesc="دیماندی", more...}, Object { MainCode=956, SubCode=2, ParamDesc="عادي", more...}]

Comment: @user3642164 i just edit your demo link. I have updated my answer so you can get the json of the selected item. option.value can be any value in your dataset json. What is your json?

Comment: got you a little bit thx again,this is my ng-option="item.SubCode as item.ParamDesc for item in BranchTypeCodeList"
and json:
[Object { MainCode=956, SubCode=1, ParamDesc="bug", more...}, Object { MainCode=956, SubCode=2, ParamDesc="normall", more...}]